# Direct connect to FirebirdSQL with FireDAC on Android?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firebird2.5, firedac

I need a direct connect to FirebirdSQL 2.x database (no DataSnap ).

- Is it possible, and how ?

Answer (score 2):

FireDAC DB connectivity depends on the existance of a DB client library for a specific platform. fbclient.dll / .so is required to connect to Firebird. There is no port of fbclient for Android. So, you cannot connect to Firebird from Android using FireDAC Firebird driver.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, FDPhysFBDriverLink are not compiled for Android

Answer (score 0):

maybe the easiest solution to retrieve or store data to and from FirebirdSql in this situation is creating small app that works as bridge between Android and FirebirdSQL. Using an unused port using Indy, it is very possible. How about format? You can use your own format, as long as it works, then everything is oke. 
Security? Sorry, i did not think about security. After connection build, security is another menu.